# Javascript regex pattern match multiple strings ( AND, OR ) against single string

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I need to filter a collection of strings based on a rather complex query - in it's "raw" form it looks like this:

```
nano* AND (regulat* OR *toxic* OR ((risk OR hazard) AND (exposure OR release)) )
```

An example of one of the strings to match against:

```
Workshop on the Second Regulatory Review on Nanomaterials, 30 January 2013, Brussels
```

So, I need to match using AND OR and wildcard characters - so, I presume I'll need to use a regex in JavaScript.

I have it all looping correctly, filtering and generally working, but I'm 100% sure my regex is wrong - and some results are being omitted wrongly - here it is:

```
/(nano[a-zA-Z])?(regulat[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z]toxic[a-zA-Z]|((risk|hazard)*(exposure|release)))/i
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I really can't abstract my mind correctly to understand this syntax!

UPDATE:

Few people are point out the importance of the order in which the regex is constructed, however I have no control over the text strings that will be searched, so I need to find a solution that can work regardless of the order or either.

UPDATE:

Eventually used a PHP solution, due to deprecation of twitter API 1.0, see pastebin for example function ( I know it's better to paste code here, but there's a lot... ):

function: http://pastebin.com/MpWSGtHK
usage: http://pastebin.com/pP2AHEvk

Thanks for all help

Comment: You might want to try [a live RegExp testing tool](http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex).

Comment: In your example string, 'nano' comes after 'regulatory', but in your regex, its the other way round. Is there any expected pattern in this such that one will always come before the other?
A few more examples would help explain your requirement.

Comment: @Barney - good advice, that's how I got this far

Comment: @Chirag64 - the strings I'm matching against were initially tweets, from this feed: https://twitter.com/nanoTOES - so, there is no order, we're just trying to reduce the number and increase the relevancy.

Comment: @QL Studio: I'm afraid you'll have to use multiple if conditions with AND & OR instead of trying to fit everything in a single regex in that case.

Comment: It *is* possible to do this in a single regex using a heroic combination of lookahead assertions, but I would advise against it, not least because you can't even use commented/verbose regexes in JavaScript, and that regex will be nearly unreadable (that is, even more unreadable than most regexes are anyway).

Comment: @TimPietzcker - very good point, regex is bordering on voodoo for me - but what about wildcard searches - can I achieve this using a standard search, or will I need to break the regex into single pieces and pass each.. that sounds like a bit of hack job.. but - would not be the first time :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A single regex is not the right tool for this, IMO:

```
/^(?=.*\bnano)(?=(?:.*\bregulat|.*toxic|(?=.*(?:\brisk\b|\bhazard\b))(?=.*(?:\bexposure\b|\brelease\b))))/i.test(subject))
```

*would* return True if the string fulfills the criteria you set forth, but I find nested lookaheads quite incomprehensible. If JavaScript supported commented regexes, it would look like this:

```
^                 # Anchor search to start of string
(?=.*\bnano)      # Assert that the string contains a word that starts with nano
(?=               # AND assert that the string contains...
 (?:              #  either
  .*\bregulat     #   a word starting with regulat
 |                #  OR
  .*toxic         #   any word containing toxic
 |                #  OR
  (?=             #   assert that the string contains
   .*             #    any string
   (?:            #    followed by
    \brisk\b      #    the word risk
   |              #    OR
    \bhazard\b    #    the word hazard
   )              #    (end of inner OR alternation)
  )               #   (end of first AND condition)
  (?=             #   AND assert that the string contains
   .*             #    any string
   (?:            #    followed by
    \bexposure\b  #    the word exposure
   |              #    OR
    \brelease\b   #    the word release
   )              #    (end of inner OR alternation)
  )               #   (end of second AND condition)
 )                #  (end of outer OR alternation)
)                 # (end of lookahead assertion)
```

Note that the entire regex is composed of lookahead assertions, so the match result itself will always be the empty string.

Instead, you could use single regexes:

```
if (/\bnano/i.test(str) &&
    ( 
        /\bregulat|toxic/i.test(str) ||
        ( 
            /\b(?:risk|hazard)\b/i.test(str) &&
            /\b(?:exposure|release)\b/i.test(str)
        )
    )
)    /* all tests pass */
```

Comment: please could you explain the [\b] - I read that "\b is a backspace character" but I'm not sure how that's relevant?

Comment: @QLStudio: In a normal string, `"\b"` is indeed a backspace character.  In a regex, `/\b/` (equivalent to `new Regex("\\b")`) is a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). This anchor matches at the start or end of an alphanumeric word. Therefore `/\brisk\b/` only matches `"risk"` or `"There is a risk!"`, but not `"brisk"` or `"risky"`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - I've moved away from javasript, because the version 1.0 of the API is shutting down, but the regexes should work almost as is in PHP I think - I'll post a complete answer when I've got it all fixed up.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions have to move through the string in order.  You have "nano" before "regulat" in the pattern, but they are swapped in the test string.  Instead of using regexen to do this, I'd stick with plain old string parsing:

```
if (str.indexOf('nano') > -1) {
    if (str.indexOf('regulat') > -1 || str.indexOf('toxic') > -1
        || ((str.indexOf('risk') > - 1 || str.indexOf('hazard') > -1)
        && (str.indexOf('exposure') > -1 || str.indexOf('release') > -1)
    )) {
        /* all tests pass */
    }
}
```

If you want to actually capture the words (e.g. get "Regulatory" from where "regulat" is, I would split the sentence by word breaks and inspect individual words.

Comment: @EP - please see my comment above, the order of the string I'm matching against is as random as it's content.. I'm just trying to "filter" over a large collection of tweets based on the regex - perhaps this is the wrong approach?

Comment: @QLStudio is my suggestion inappropriate for that?

Comment: @EP - yes, sorry - your solution solves the order problem.. but can I still use wildcard ( * ) characters in a normal JS search?

Comment: I need to match nano* ( eg. nanotechnology ) and regulat* ( eg. regulation )

Comment: `indexOf` works with character sets not words .. so `"nanotechnology".indexOf('nano')` returns `0` (which is greater than `-1`)

Comment: @EP - ok, so.. I've added this and it's working - happy to be moving away from regex.. I'll do a little more testing and accept later on  -thanks!

Comment: @QLStudio: The only problem with this solution is that it will also match words that only contain your search substrings (for example, `risk` is contained in `briskly`, so this algorithm would report a false positive match. If you need to match entire words (and your examples of `nano*` and `*toxic*` suggest you do), then you need word boundaries that you only get with regex matches.